# Why doesn't 'continue' work in page?

Tags: loop, slug

OK, so I'm working with a template (I have contacted the developer and they were of no help, so I'm modifying the template page as needed). The template displays portfolio items, using the following code:

```
            <div class="container filter-portfolio clearfix">
        <ul id="portfolio" class="clearfix">
                <?php 
                        $type = 'portfolio';
                        $args=array( 'post_type' => $type, 'posts_per_page' => -1 );
                        query_posts( $args );   

                        if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();                  
                        $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'portfolio_categories' ); ?>

                        if (has_post_thumbnail()) {                 
                            $thumb = get_post_thumbnail_id();
                            $thumb_w = '460';
                            $thumb_h = '272';
                            $image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full');
                            $image_url = $image_src [0];
                            $attachment_url = wp_get_attachment_url($thumb, 'full');
                            $image = aq_resize($attachment_url, $thumb_w, $thumb_h, true);                          
                        }           


                        $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'grid-thumb');

                            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                                    $cats[0] = $term->name;
                                    $catname = join($cats);     
                                    $catname = preg_replace('/\s/', '', $catname);                                  
                            }
                        $title= get_the_title();
                        $title= explode(' ',$title);
                        $title[0]= '<span class="bold">'.$title[0].'</span>';
                        $title= implode(' ',$title);
                    ?>  

            <!-- PORTFOLIO ITEM -->
                <li data-id="id-<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" data-type="<?php 
                            $terms = get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'portfolio_categories','',' , ','' ); 
                            $terms = preg_replace('/\s/','', $terms);
                            $terms = strip_tags( $terms );
                            $terms = preg_replace('/[\s,\-!]/',' ', $terms);
                            echo $terms;
                            ?>" class="four columns m-bot-25">
                            <div class="content-container-white">
                                <div class="view view-first">
                                    <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
                                    <div class="mask">
                                        <h2><?php echo $title; ?></h2>
                                        <a href="<?php echo $attachment_url; ?>" class="lightbox zoom info"></a>
                                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="link info"></a>
                                    </div>  
                                </div>
                                <div class="lw-item-caption-container">
                                    <a class="a-invert" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" ><?php echo $title; ?></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                </li>

      <?php endwhile; ?>    
        </ul>

    </div>
```

Basically, I need to only display posts that match a certain slug, which can be retrieved off $terms. However, when I try the following code modification:

```
if( $terms->slug != 'product-gallery' ) continue;
```

placed after the $terms = get_the_terms(...) line, it would seem that The Loop is broken, and no posts are displayed at all on the page. It's important that I can filter the posts, and by slug, as I can't modify the theme very much, and the client needs to be able to add/remove posts by categories for which there are slugs.

Disclaimer: I am new to the WP environment, php, and mysql. However, I am a quick learned and I have plenty of coding experience in C++, Java, Perl, etc. I'm just new to web development.

What am I missing or doing wrong for my goal?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[get_the_terms](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms) returns an array of terms - so `$terms` is an array.

Therefore, your condition:

```
if( $terms->slug != 'product-gallery' )
```

will always return false, and therefore skip every post every time.

Try

```
if ( in_array( 'product-gallery', $terms ) ) continue;
```

The above is untested.